# Visual Studio Locks Up with High CPU Usage

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am struggling with an issue with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. It periodically becomes unstable and consumes high CPU usage.

It installed sysinternals and discovered that it is hitting the same windows registry keys, over and over and over again.

```
1:47:35.7102365 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegOpenKey  HKLM\Hardware\DeviceMap\Video   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read
1:47:35.7102519 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegQueryValue   HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\VIDEO\\Device\Video0    SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 202, Data: \Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{EC5CE5A2-F3F0-4FBA-B911-D6E9CEE6A3B4}\0000
1:47:35.7102789 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegCloseKey HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\VIDEO   SUCCESS 
1:47:35.7102990 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegOpenKey  HKLM\Hardware\DeviceMap\VIDEO   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read, Maximum Allowed
1:47:35.7103122 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegQueryValue   HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\VIDEO\MaxObjectNumber   SUCCESS Type: REG_DWORD, Length: 4, Data: 4
1:47:35.7103297 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegCloseKey HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\VIDEO   SUCCESS 
1:47:35.7103477 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegOpenKey  HKLM\Hardware\DeviceMap\Video   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read
1:47:35.7103601 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegQueryValue   HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\VIDEO\\Device\Video1    SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 202, Data: \Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{EC5CE5A2-F3F0-4FBA-B911-D6E9CEE6A3B4}\0001
1:47:35.7103845 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegOpenKey  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\CONTROL\VIDEO\{EC5CE5A2-F3F0-4FBA-B911-D6E9CEE6A3B4}\0001 REPARSE Desired Access: Read
1:47:35.7104033 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegOpenKey  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\CONTROL\VIDEO\{EC5CE5A2-F3F0-4FBA-B911-D6E9CEE6A3B4}\0001 SUCCESS Desired Access: Read
1:47:35.7104178 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegCloseKey HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\VIDEO   SUCCESS 
1:47:35.7104290 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000\PruningMode NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 52
1:47:35.7104422 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegCloseKey HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000 SUCCESS 
1:47:35.7104580 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegOpenKey  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_90C3104D&REV_09\3&11583659&0&10 SUCCESS Desired Access: Query Value, Maximum Allowed
1:47:35.7104824 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_90C3104D&REV_09\3&11583659&0&10\HardwareID  BUFFER OVERFLOW Length: 271
1:47:35.7104965 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegCloseKey HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_90C3104D&REV_09\3&11583659&0&10 SUCCESS 
1:47:35.7105128 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegOpenKey  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_90C3104D&REV_09\3&11583659&0&10 SUCCESS Desired Access: Query Value, Maximum Allowed
1:47:35.7105346 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_90C3104D&REV_09\3&11583659&0&10\HardwareID  SUCCESS Type: REG_MULTI_SZ, Length: 292, Data: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_90C3104D&REV_09, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_90C3104D, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&CC_030000, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&CC_0300
1:47:35.7105526 AM  devenv.exe  2560    RegCloseKey HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_90C3104D&REV_09\3&11583659&0&10 SUCCESS
```

This loops, hundreds, if not thousands of times and doesn't appear to end until I END TASK on Visual Studio. Any ideas why this is happening?

My machine is a core i7 with 8GB RAM. I'm not currently running many other applications. Memory Usage is 5.6 GB / 7.9 GB. Disk usage is low and stable. Just CPU is going nuts!

Comment: +1 for going deeper in the problem's root!

Comment: The registry usage does not explain high CPU usage, it at best is a side-effect of whatever is going on inside devenv.exe.  Something with video, it seems, but certainly no guarantee.  This is almost invariably an issue caused by an add-in, so start disabling them one by one.